# Firebug command line & editor not working

Tags: firefox, firebug

When I type few commands like this:

```
$("#popup").click();
var x = 1;
x;
```

the commands are simply copied to the prompt window.
They are not executed !

What is wrong with my Firebug (Firefox) addon, please ?

Firefox v 43, Firebug v2.0.12b1
[image]

but with Chrome everything works fine
[image]

Comment: First of all you should ensure that you have the latest versions of Firefox and Firebug installed. Does it happen on all pages? A screenshot of what you see would also be good.

Comment: screen shots attached

Comment: Little note: The beta channel didn't get updated with a new version, but the latest version of Firebug is 2.0.13. I've now [asked to update the beta version](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebug/C6MFAOfYaNk).

Comment: Uninstall the current plugin and redownload and install the latest firebug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a [thread in the Firebug forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/firebug/U5Lik1KetOc/discussion), this may be caused by a conflict with other extensions. The extensions named there are:

- Wappalyzer
- Ghostery 5.2.1
- The easiest Xdebug 1.2
- Skype Click to Call
- A Greasemonkey script
- Nimbus Screen Capture
- 1Password
- Coupons at Checkout

So, if you have one of those extensions installed or a Greasemonkey script running, disabling it and try it again.

If that doesn't help, I suggest you follow the steps described in the [Firebug first aid page](https://getfirebug.com/firstaid) and [report that bug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/new). The steps are:

1. Open the Firefox Error Console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>). Any errors related to Firebug? Copy them and remember to include them in your report.
2. Create a new profile, install Firebug, reproduce the problem. Still a bug? Report the problem, else
3. Return to your previous profile, open the Add-ons Manager via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or Firefox menu button > *Add-ons* or `about:addons` to disable all extensions except Firebug. Solved? Enable the other extensions again one by one until you find the buggy one and report it, else
4. Open the troubleshooting information via Firefox menu button > *?* > *Troubleshooting Information*, click *Show Folder*, open *prefs.js* in a text editor, copy all lines containing `extensions.firebug` into a separate text file, reset all options (via Firebug icon menu (upper left corner) > *Options* > *Reset All Firebug Options*), reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching the created file, else
5. In the profile folder go to *firebug/*, move the file *breakpoints.json* (if it doesn't exist, go to step 4) out of that folder, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching your *breakpoints.json* (**Attention:** *breakpoints.json* contains the URLs of all breakpoints you set, so make sure there's nothing, that shouldn't be public), else
6. In the profile folder under *firebug/* move the file *annotations.json* (if it doesn't exist, go to step 5) out of that folder, reproduce the problem. Solved? Report the problem attaching your *annotations.json* (**Attention:** *annotations.json* contains the URLs of all pages you enabled Firebug for, so make sure there's nothing, that shouldn't be public)

Comment: I am not sure what helped me but now it works.
I did reinstall Firebug and disable / enable all extension.
Now it works. Thanks for the help !

Comment: I lost my command line and control shift L wouldn't fix it.  Resetting the options to the defaults fixed it!  Many thanks for posting this!